# Aligning element to left side of above element

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a to-do app to get the hang of the basics.

I'm trying to align an `<li>` element below and to the left of the text box that is above it, not the center, something like:

```
        ######
        ###
```

It currently formats like the following:

```
        ######
         ###
```

I've tried putting the textbox and `<li>` element in a 'container' but I'm still missing something.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'fira sans', sans-serif;
}

body {
  color: white;
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  /* Add this for horizontal alignment */
  height: 100vh;
  /* Added to make sure the container takes the full height of the viewport */
}

#myInput {
  border-radius: 1rem;
  padding: 1rem;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  margin-right: 1rem;
  background-color: lightgray;
}

#myInput::placeholder {
  color: grey;
}

#list {
  padding-left: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-left: 0;
}

#list li {}
```

```html
<container class="container">
  <h1>To Do 2023</h1>
  <form method="get" id="myForm" onsubmit="event.preventDefault();">
    <input type="text" id="myInput" placeholder="Enter Text...">
    <input type="submit">
  </form>
  <ul id="list">
    <li>hi</li>
    <li>my</li>
    <li>friend</li>
  </ul>
</container>
```

Any ideas on where I'm going wrong? I've tried so many things I may have introduced other issues

Comment: There's no such thing as `<container>` in HTML5. Use a valid tag like `<div>` or i.e: `<main>`, `<article>` etc. Also, avoid HTML inline `on*` JS handlers like `onsubmit`. Use [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) from JS instead.

Answer (score 0):

Add a min-width to your `.container` and center it using `margin: 0 auto;`.
Make your form `flex`

```js
document.querySelector("#myForm").addEventListener("submit", (evt) => {
  evt.preventDefault();
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'fira sans', sans-serif;
  outline: 1px solid red;
}

body {
  color: white;
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
}

#myForm {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  gap: 1rem;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100dvh; /* dynamic viewport height! */
  max-width: 400px; /* set a desired max-width */
  margin: auto; /* horiz. center */
}

input,
button {
  padding: 1rem;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  border: 0;
}

#save {
  flex: 1;
  background: #0bf;
}

#list {
  padding-left: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  align-self: flex-start;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <title>To do app</title>
</head>

<body>
  <main class="container">
  
    <h1>To Do 2023</h1>
    
    <form id="myForm">
      <input id="myInput" type="text" placeholder="Enter Text...">
      <button id="save" type="submit">Save</button>
    </form>

    <ul id="list">
      <li>hi</li>
      <li>my</li>
      <li>friend</li>
    </ul>
    
  </main>
  
  <script src="app.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```